# How to replace with values with adjacent column using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe, df1,

After outer join the df is below

df1 have 4 columns ['A','B','C','D']

```
ID,A,B,C,D
1,Nan,Nan,c,d
1,a,b,c,d
```

- I need to replace the `Nan` values in df['A'] is  with df['C']
- I need to replace the `Nan` values in df['B'] is  with df['D']

expected out is below

```
ID,A,B,C,D
1,c,d,c,d
1,a,b,c,d
```

in the first row df['A'] replaced with df['C'], if df['A'] then it has to retrieve df['A'] only

in the first row df['B'] replaced with df['D'], if df['B'] then it has to retrieve df['D'] only

Comment: use ```bfill(axis=1)```

Comment: What about if you have: `[NaN, b, NaN, d]`, or `[a, NaN, NaN, d]`?

Comment: @jcaliz, i dont have that it is [NaN, b, NaN, d]

Comment: Just making sure to cover all cases, what about the second one?

Comment: Ok, in this current data set its not there, but it may come later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fill the column with the second-after column, one way is to [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) specifying the `value` parameter:

```
df.A.fillna(value=df.C, inplace=True)
df.B.fillna(value=df.D, inplace=True)
```

If for some reason you have a lot of columns and wants to keep filling `NaN` using values on the second-after column then use a for loop on the first `n-2` columns

```
columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

for i in range(len(columns)-2):
    df[columns[i]].fillna(df[columns[i+2]], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Or `df.bfill(axis=1, inplace=True)`

Comment: i have updated the question can you check this please